# Scheme if pair end with a space char,the result will have one dot between two element

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

if pair end with a space char,
why result value contains one dot(.)?
what does this dot(.) mean?

```
(cons 1 2 )
;Value 2: (1 . 2)

(car (cons 1 2 ))
;Value: 1

(cdr (cons 1 2 ))
;Value: 2
```

this one seems stupid, because pair only contain two element.

i just want to know why the first expression echo one dot in the result!

```
(cadr (cons 1 2 ))
;The object 2, passed as an argument to safe-car, is not a pair.
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.
```

thanks!

Comment: It has nothing to do with the space char.  `(cons 1 2 )` is the same as `(cons 1 2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CONS constructs a pair. A pair of two things. It is written as `(firstthing . secondthing)`.

If the second thing is an empty list, it is written as `(firstthing)`. It is the same as `(firstthing . ())`.

Since `cons` constructs a cons, the result of `(cons 1 2)` is `(1 . 2)`.

`(cadr (cons 1 2))` is an error. It is `(car (cdr (cons 1 2))`. `(cdr (cons 1 2)` is `2`. Now `(car 2)` is wrong. You can't take the *car* of `2`. `2` is a number, not a cons.

If you want to create a list, which is made of cons cells or the empty list, then use the function `list`.

Comment: @ray: A pair of two things. It is written as (firstthing . secondthing). That's the definition. That's why it is there. It could be written differently, but that's how it is defined in Lisp even before the dinosaurs walked on this planet. ;-)

Comment: sorry,i just start learning SICP, now i finally know that the dot is just a way of representing cons.whatever, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The dot is not an "element" of the result, it is the way in which Scheme memorizes lists, i.e. as concatenated pairs.

For example, the list

```
(1 2 3)
```

is memorized in this form:

```
(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))
```

Comment: This is not accurate, Scheme, or any other lisp, doesn't memorize dots! It prints dots to represent conses, usually conses whose `cdr` is not null or another cons, but that may be configurable in your implementation.